# ajax on select throws exception "The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable"

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a form with 2 selects and a submit button. Changing the value of the first select element should trigger an ajax call to update the values of the second. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormAjaxResponseBuilder->buildResponse() (line 67
```

Code is at http://pastebin.com/r4Y3q8ic

From a bit of debug it seems that Core thinks that the submit button triggered the ajax call, not the select.

I've tried various ways of specifying the callback, but they all cause the same error.

Comment: So after some further debugging it seems:

1. The ajax part works on the homepage - but not on pages that contain a views exposed form.

2. On the homepage where the ajax select is updated, the form is always submitted with the old values, and not that of the element selected in the new drop-down...